# JSP simple insertion cannot run in class

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, oop

I am trying to do a simple insertion like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO UserBanker(firstname,lastname,gender,mobile,email)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
int rowsAffected = 0;
try{

    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, "abc");
    stmt.setString(2, "abc");
    stmt.setString(3, "abc");
    stmt.setString(4, "abc");
    stmt.setString(5, "abc");
    rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And its works and **able to insert**.But when I trying this approach in oop like below

```
public class User{
     ...
}

public class Banker extends User{

...

public int store(Connection con){
String sql = "INSERT INTO UserBanker(firstname,lastname,gender,mobile,email)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
int rowsAffected = 0;
try{
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, super.getFirstName());
    stmt.setString(2, super.getLastName());
    stmt.setString(3, super.getGender());
    stmt.setString(4, this.getMobile());
    stmt.setString(5, this.getEmail());
    rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rowsAffected;
}

...

}//end of class
```

And I call it like below

```
Banker b1= new Banker();
...set all value...
b1.store(con);
```

The oop script above **always return unexpected result which is 0.**

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I am sorry , I fixed my word

Comment: In the preparedstatement from the first example there are no single quotes around the question marks, but there are in the second example. Is this intentional?

Comment: post how you set instance variables of the Banker class

Comment: I added more code , I think my problem is half of the variable is from super and two of them is from the own class , am i accessing it correctly?

Comment: is their any possibility to that value being null

Comment: No , I do validate the form , the code wont run unless user key in all data

Comment: most probably your code throws exception can you post stacktrace

Comment: try printing stmt.toString() before running the query. see if you're inserting the values properly.

Comment: Im having problem print from class.... I can't put out.println() , because it produce error , netbean is preventing me from compile

Comment: are you re using connection multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I believe something happen to my object behaviour , Thanks Exbury for pointing about `e.printStackTrace();` for my query. **the output is 'the column mobile is not valid' , I am missing a column in my table**

Answer (score 1):

> The oop script above always return unexpected result which is 0.

That's because there's an SQLException being thrown in your `try` block and you're swallowing it in the `catch` block. Thus `rowsAffected` retains its initial value.

Likely the exception being thrown is due to a syntax error in your `insert` statement. Remove the single quotes `'?'` from around the parameter markers `?` and let JDBC do that for you like it's supposed to.